# Unable to access data from a form submission in a POST request

Tags: reactjs, flask

On submission of a form, I would like to make a `POST` request with contents of that form, then do stuff with it, and eventually return it back to the frontend to be rendered. However, when I make the `POST` request to Flask, in Flask,  *`request.form`* returns an *`ImmuateMultiDict([])`* and *`request.form["videoURL"]`* gives a *`BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'videoURL'`* in console. If I do *`request.data`*, then I see what I want *`b'{"videoURL":"asdkljasldkjasd"}'`*, but as a string.

Here is `App.js` that has the form and also what I want to render back when I finish the `POST` request,

```
import React , { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
    const [videoURL, setVideoURL] = useState('')
    const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState([])

    async function fetchData() {
        fetch('/test',  
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    'videoURL': videoURL
                })
            })  
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setFetchedData(data))
    }

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        fetchData()
    }

    return (
        <>
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label>Video URL</label>
                    <input type="text" value={videoURL} onChange={e => setVideoURL(e.target.value)}/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div className="container">
            <h2>Top Users</h2>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Rank</th>
                        <th>User</th>
                        <th># of Messages</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        fetchedData.map((item, i) => (
                            <tr key={item.user}>
                                <td>{i + 1}</td>
                                <td>{item.user}</td>
                                <td>{item.messages}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

export default App;
```

Here is the backend with `Flask`,

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/test', methods=["POST"])
def test():
    print(request.data) # returns b'{"videoURL":"asdkljasldkjasd"}'
    print(request.form) # returns ImmutableMultiDict([])
    url = request.form["videoURL"] # console returns BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: 
                                   The browser (or proxy) sent a request that 
                                   this server could not understand. KeyError: 
                                   'videoURL'
    .....
    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your fetch function

```
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
```

Comment: I tried it, but it still gave me the immutable dictionary problem. A temporary solution is that I just decode the request.data and index what I want, but I want to add more JSON data, so this will be extremely tedious.